# Angular RxJs - Crud Operations

Tags: angular, rxjs, crud

```
public ngOnInit() {
  this.getUsers();
}

public getUsers() {
  this.userService.getUsers(this.listId).pipe(take(1)).subscribe(data => {
    if (data.result.length) {
      this.users = data.result;
    } else {
      const user = new UserModel();
      this.users = [user];
    }
    this.setupForm();
  });

}

public deleteUser(userId: number) {
  this.userService.delete(this.listId, userId)
    .subscribe(() => this.getUsers())
}
```

How would you recommand me, when I'm deleting an user from a table, to get back all the users? Is ok to call this.getUsers() method in .subscribe()? Or should I try to call it in .pipe()

Answer (score 2):

I usually create an observable for getting data that updates whenever there's a CRUD operation. Here is a schematic example:

```
edit$ = this.editClick$
  .pipe(
     switchMapTo(this.latestFormValue$),
     switchMap(formValue => this.api.edit(formValue))
  )

delete$ = this.deleteClick$
  .pipe(
    switchMap(id => this.api.delete(id))
  )

getData$ = merge(this.edit$, this.delete$)
  .pipe(
    switchMap(() => this.api.getData(this.param))
  )
```

I will also say avoiding imperative and stateful code has been very helpful in reducing complexity and bugs. I only use state in components for the simplest things, such as a component with a single internal variable and one or two actions.

But even seemingly simple things like a breadcrumbs component that has inputs for navigation links have had race conditions that I had to fix by making it more reactive (in that case I got the inputs from `route.params` instead of the `Input`s).

I would also avoid having any sort of body for `subscribe`. That is what the different operators are there for, and the operators make it clearer what you are intending as well as forcing you to think more reactively. If you really want to make `users` a state variable (I would recommend making it an observable and subscribing with `AsyncPipe`), then you should set it in a `tap` operator to make it obvious that you're introducing a side effect to the observable.

And in fact, if you set it up the way I've shown above and use `AsyncPipe`, you will not have to subscribe to any of those observables. `AsyncPipe` will subscribe to `getData$` and `getData$` will in turn subscribe to `edit$` and `delete$`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends, if you want to get fresh data from the API every time you delete then you can use `switchMap` operator from `import { filter, map, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';`

Here is an example of how to use it:

```
public deleteUser(userId: number): void {
    this.userService
      .delete(this.listId, userId)
      .pipe(switchMap(() => this.userService.getUsers(this.listId)))
      .subscribe((res) => (this.users = res));
  }
```

Second solution would be removing the delete item from a list of users using javascript `splice` function:

```
    public deleteUser(userId: number): void {
            this.userService
              .delete(this.listId, userId)
              .subscribe((res) => {
            const index = this.users.findIndex(u => u.userId === userId);
            if (index > -1) {
                   this.users.aplice(index, 1)
            }
            });
          }
```

Comment: I would suggest always first approach! it's called reactive programming no need to use native js methods

Comment: I don't think it's the best solution, because I want to setup the form again, so as a conclusion I want to call getUsers() function again, after I deleted an user

Comment: It is not a good practice to nest subscriptions. I suggest you move the logic that is within the subscription to a separate function